# CodeBlocks: Change the style of { } completion

Tags: c++, autocomplete, coding-style, codeblocks, curly-braces

I am currently using CodeBlocks as my C++ IDE. If I am coding in "Allman Style", by which I mean this:

```
foo()
{
    // cursor goes here
}
```

the brace completion is very satisfactory. Upon typing the opening {, it immediately completes the closing } and sets the cursor between them, with correct indentation level.

However, if I want to code in this other style, which looks like this:

```
foo() {
    // code goes here
}
```

The brace completion is almost annoying for me. After typing the opening {, only after pressing Return does it complete the closing }. Besides, what I end up with is this:

```
foo() {
|}
```

whereas '|' is the cursor. As you can see, the closing brace is still on the same line. Additionally, the indentation level isn't correct. I would like CodeBlocks to give me the following result upon typing the opening {

```
foo() {
    |
}
```

Whereas '|' represents the cursor position.

For the life of me I can't figure out which setting I need for this. I am pretty sure it's possible, since it works so nicely for the first style.

I hope that I explained my problem precise enough and that someone can help me out with this.

Smoothware

Comment: well.. seems like I'm going to stick to Allman style for now... :p

Comment: have looked, seems to be bug

Answer (score 3):

Code::Blocks version 17.12
Settings->Editor->Source formatter-> select Bracket style Google or Mozilla
Use AStyle from context menu for formatting any file

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I just tried this with the recent nightly build (svn 11825) and this does not solve the problem I described. The behavior is still exactly as I described several years ago, lol.